# IdentityServer and windows authentication through wsfederation

Tags: identityserver3, identityserver4

this is newbie question about identityServer and windows authentication. The samples provided with IdentityServer3 with windows authentication seem to implement it using WSFederation, like the one provided in this link https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/WebHost%20(Windows%20Auth%20All-in-One).
The newest samples with identityserver4 are using a different approach without Federation. Are these approaches equivalent? Are there benefits in one approach over the other.I can understand using Federation for ADFS, but not for Windows authentication with AD. I know I am missing something can't figure it out. What is it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identity Server 4 is based on .NET Core which currently does not support WS-Federation so if that is a requirement you should stick to Identity Server 3 on the "standard" framework.

According to the devs there's a "test" version out for WS-Fed but if it will be included in the final release of .NET Core 2.0 is still uncertain.

See https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/500

Comment: Can you comment on the benefits or difference of using Federation, when theses samples just do AD authentication? This is what I don't understand.Thanks

Comment: Microsoft is moving towards using OpenId Connect as their standard but before that they used their own (WS-Fed) protocol.

I believe that some older versions of ADFS and for example Windows Authentication relies on WS-Fed and has no support for OpenId Connect so it basically comes down to whether your current infrastructure supports OpenId Connect. Keep in mind that WS-Fed is coming to .NET Core (and therefor IdentityServer) but there's no real release date yet.